# Defining a seasonal ARIMA model in R

Tags: r, forecasting, arima, energy

This is my first post as I'm struggling with coding in R.

I'm investigating power prices in the Danish electricity market and want to test the forecast power of those prices upon different model selection techniques. My data is hourly power prices within the timeframe of 2021.09.01 - 2021.11.25.

However, I face issues in defining my seasonal adjusted ARIMA model.

After running the necessary R packages, I execute the following code:

```
**expforecast = function(yt, ar, ma, ini, n){
  if (is.list(yt)){yt=as.matrix(yt)}
  t <- length(yt)
  n_for <- t-n-ini+1
  e_arma <- rep(0, n_for)
  for(z in 1:n_for){
    y_t=yt[1:(ini+z-1)]
    model1 <- arima(y_t, order=c(ar,0,ma), method="ML")
    y1_hat <- predict(model1, h=n)
    e_arma[z] <- yt[(ini+z+n-1)] - y1_hat$pred[1]
  }
  return(e_arma)
}**

**El_spot <- read_excel("El-spot.xls")
View(El_spot)**

**NoOfHours <- as.numeric(ymd_hms("2021-11-25 00:00:00") - ymd_hms("2021-01-01 00:00:00"))*24
ymd_hms("2021-01-01 00:00:00") + hours(0:NoOfHours)**

**y <- ts(El_spot$c1, start=1, frequency=24*7)**
```

Please bear in mind that I use frequency as 24/7 due to daily and weekly seasonality (correct me if I'm wrong). The 24/7 frequency creates ~13 weeks.

Furthermore I run the following code to test for stationarity in my time-series:

```
**decomp = stl(y, "periodic")
deseasonal_cnt <- seasadj(decomp)
plot(decomp)
[enter image description here][2]
adf.test(y, alternative = "stationary")**
```

I receive a p-value of .01, thus stationarity is obtained. However, when running the ACF and PACF plot, I find clear autocorrelation pattern.

```
**Acf(y, main='')**
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DT6SU.png)

```
**Pacf(y, main='')**
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOaJF.png)

I hope some of you skilled guys can assist me with this struggle and maybe recommend a seasonal ARIMA model to go forward with.

Comment: I suggest you read [Forecasting: Principles and Practice](https://otexts.com/fpp3/). It contains some examples with regards to electricity prices but the book explains everything you need to know.

Comment: Thanks for the literature recommendation. I'm familiar with Prof. Hynd. However, I do not find any explanation for my lag series of 0.05, 0.10.., 0.20. (maximum lag in ACF), and lag series of 0, 168 and 336 in my PACF. I know stationarity can be obtained while finding serial autocorrelation. However, I can't find explanations and suggestions for an ARIMA model when all spikes goes beyond critical line in ACF plot.

Comment: You could try differencing your data as explained in chapter 9.1 and more examples in chapter 9.9 (from fpp3 that is, chapter 8 in fpp2). Or see if a log function would help to create more stability.